# How to see a window preview in xlib?

Tags: x11, window

I am making a window manager and for the Alt+Tab screen (for switching windows) I want to show the user a live preview of the window. Xlib does not seem to have any functions relating to this.

How can I get a live preview of a window? Perhaps through an extension or another library entirely? I need this preview regardless of the window being mapped.

Comment: XGetImage ? (from the xlib) https://linux.die.net/man/3/xgetimage

Comment: @MC68020 The issue with XGetImage is that the window cannot be obscured. However, this does not work for a switcher where obscured windows must still be detected properly.